# How to get old contacts back from Exchange on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, exchange

A user has an iPhone that is using Exchange email.

The email password recently changed and the iPhone kept trying to connect using the old password, which kept locking him out of his email on his laptop and tablet.

I tried to change the Exchange details on the iPhone but it refused to authenticate, and I decided it would be just simpler to remove and re-add the Exchange account on his phone.

After I re-created the Exchange credentials, all was up and running. Thinking at first that all was sorted out, he later realized that most of his phone numbers were gone.

Is there a way to have the iPhone download the contacts from the Exchange server?

PS the iPhone6 is relatively new and I am not accustomed to iOS interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this app to import your contacts from CSV file to your iPhone:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contacts-in-import-csv-contacts/id549639443?mt=8

You can send CSV file to app via email attachment or iTunes. More details:
http://csvcontacts.wordpress.com/user-instructions/

You can handle phone number types correctly ("mobile","work","home"), import birdthays from any date format and many more.

Answer (score 0):

If [configured correctly](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201729), you can sync the contacts with no additional software:

> You can sync Mail, Contacts, Calendars, Reminders, and Notes. When you're finished, tap Save.
>
> [image: Exchange sync options]

Comment: I just used the default settings, which I am confident should have looked like that screenshot, but no contacts were imported.

Comment: Can you confirm by another route that the contacts reside on the Exchange server? OWA, Outlook on a Windows machine?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed with OWA using windows machine. Made a copy just in case.

Comment: Maybe this answer may be of help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/186617/38539